# Looking for way to read table content in HTML file from Python3

Tags: html, python-3.x

I am looking for reading NIFTY 50 Low and High values from the below web page in Python3.

https://www.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/live_index_watch.htm

I tried using bs4 and selenium webdrivers to read these values. Could you please let me know how can I read them?

Regards,
Ram

Comment: try beautifulsoup.

Comment: @DanFarrell bs4 is beautifulsoup, which OP mentioned they have tried already

Comment: @Ram, how did you try using bs4 and selenium? can you show us your code? then we can provide suggestions or solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing your code with Selenium and bs4 we don't know why it didn't work for you. But this code seems to work:

```
import bs4
import requests
from selenium import webdriver

url = 'https://www.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/live_index_watch.htm'

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('headless')                # disable Chrome browser GUI interface
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'path_to_chromedriver.exe', options=options)
driver.get(url)

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')

table = soup.find('table', id='liveIndexWatch') # get the first table
nifty_50_row = table.find_all('tr')[2]          # get first row of prices

high_low = nifty_50_row.find_all('td')[4:6]     # get 'high'/'low' columns

# format output
print('NIFTY 50 High: {h} Low: {l}'.format(h=high_low[0].text, l=high_low[1].text))
```

prints:

```
NIFTY 50 High: 10,834.20 Low: 10,764.45         # current values
```